# Return a negative value

Tags: python, list, if-statement, negative-number

I'm trying to implement a function where I have 2 players and their payoffs depends on their actions.

```
def game(action1,action2):

  if action1 == "a" and action2 == "a":
     payoff1 = 1
     payoff2 = 1
  elif action1 == "a" and action2 == "b":
     payoff1 = -5
     payoff2 = 3
  elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "a":
     payoff1 = 3
     payoff2 = -5
  elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "b":
     payoff1 = 2
     payoff2 = 2
 return payoff1 , payoff2
```

Then I would have strategy for this game (example):

```
def TitForTat(round_num, previous_action):
    if round_num == 0:
       action = "a"
    else:
       action = previous_action
  return action

def AlwaysDefect():
  return "b"

action1 = TitForTat (0,'c')
action2 = AlwaysDefect()

game (action1,action2)
```

This returns an error:

```
local variable 'payoff1' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to initialize them to "0" , but the same.
The exact functions works very well if I have all positive values.

EDIT:

So sorry for the typo error. And function AlwaysDefect() returns "b" and "d".

Comment: `payyoff2` --> `payoff2 `.

Comment: Are  `action1` and `action2` limited to values of `"a"` or `"b"` going into your `game` function? The error implies that none of your `if` conditions  triggered. If either `action1` or `action2` has a value other than `"a"` or `"b"` you're going to get that error. It looks like one of your actions might be `"c"` but you don't take care of that case in `game`.

Comment: Replace `payyoff2 = 2` by `payoff2 = 2` in the first step

Comment: You need to add an `else` clause in your game function to handle exceptional circumstances

Comment: You can make `game` much simpler. For instance, you can do `if (action1,action2)==('a',b'): return (1,1)`. You could also replace the entire function with one line: `{('a,'a'):(1,1),('a','b'):(-5,3),('b','a'):(3,-5),('b','b'):(2,2)}[(action1,action2)]`

Comment: @Acccumulation Thank you very much for your suggestion, tried that and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much chaff in your function call. Use a dictionary:

```
def game(action1, action2):
    payoffs = {
        ('a', 'a'): (1, 1),  ('a', 'b'): (-5, 3),
        ('b', 'a'): (3, -5), ('b', 'b'): (2, 2)
    }
    return payoffs.get((action1, action2), (0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements arent catching if the action is c or d this leads to the payoff1 and payoff2 to not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that `AlwaysDefect` function return 'd' or 'b'?

Now that it return 'd', you don't get into none of your if statements and you don't have a definition for either payoff1 or payoff2

Also a typo: `payyoff2` -> `payoff2`

You can set a default statement in order to fix it (At the else section):

```
def game(action1,action2):

  if action1 == "a" and action2 == "a":
     payoff1 = 1
     payoff2 = 1
  elif action1 == "a" and action2 == "b":
     payoff1 = -5
     payoff2 = 3
  elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "a":
     payoff1 = 3
     payoff2 = -5
  elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "b":
     payoff1 = 2
     payoff2 = 2
  else:
     payoff1 = 0 # or any other value
     payoff2 = 0 # or any other value
  return payoff1, payoff2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize both payoff to something because if your actions don't fall into a specific case, you endup returning nothing. So add in a default else so that your function return default payoffs the following code should help you solve your problem mate.

```
def game(action1,action2):


    if action1 == "a" and action2 == "a":
        payoff1 = 1
        payoff2 = 1
    elif action1 == "a" and action2 == "b":
        payoff1 = -5
        payoff2 = 3
    elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "a":
        payoff1 = 3
        payoff2 = -5
    elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "b":
        payoff1 = 2
        payoff2 = 2
    else:
        payoff1= 0
        payoff2=0


    return payoff1 , payoff2
```

This should technically prevent you from having that reference error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in this code.

```
def game(action1,action2):
  # 1. this if/else chain only handles input values of "a" or "b"
  if action1 == "a" and action2 == "a":
     payoff1 = 1
     payoff2 = 1
  elif action1 == "a" and action2 == "b":
     payoff1 = -5
     payoff2 = 3
  elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "a":
     payoff1 = 3
     payoff2 = -5
  elif action1 == "b" and action2 == "b":
     payoff1 = 2
     # 2. this is misspelt, so payoff2 never gets declared for input "b","b"
     payyoff2 = 2

 return payoff1 , payoff2
```

1. the code for `game` *only* works for inputs in `("a","b")`x`("a","b")` but there is no error checking, and in fact the code you posted *does* provide inputs outside that range
2. one of the valid inputs (`"b","b"`) will still fail because you misspelt "payoff". Less verbose code has fewer opportunities for spelling mistakes, but really this is something you should find in testing.

   action1 = TitForTat (0,'c')
   action2 = AlwaysDefect()

Why not *print* your arguments before you pass them to your function? Or print the arguments inside the function? Or step into the function in `pdb` and look at them?

You've set them to `"a", "d"` here, and `TitForTat` *could* have produced `"c"`. Neither `"c"` nor `"d"` are handled at all in your `game` function.